# Calling Class By Name or Select Case/Switch?

Tags: c#, vb.net, reflection

VB.NET, but C# would also do.

I have a `MustInherit` base class and 170 inherited classes based on that. Why so many? Because each inherited class does something different in `Sub New()`. The inherited types do not add any new properties, but do have different private fields. They simply process different sets of known variables differently. So think like this:

```vb
Public MustInherit Class Base
     Public Property Width
End Class

Public Class Child1
     Inherits Base
     Private z as Integer = 7
     Public Sub New(x as integer)
           Width = 20 * x * 7
     End Sub
End Class

Public Class Child170
     Inherits Base
     Private y as Integer = 4
     Public Sub New(x as integer)
           Width = 5 * x / y
     End Sub
End Class
```

In reality, what's in the `Sub New` is a ton of processing instructions based on what is sent in (e.g. `X as Integer`). Those processing instructions will work with a large number of private variables that sit in the inherited class.

Also, I'll know which child I need to create based on a string variable that is named the same thing like `child1` or `child170`.

So, with so many inherited children, what's the best approach here (fastest, shortest amount to write, best performance, etc.)

Options:

1. Use a `Select Case` to call and create one of 170 different classes, like:

   ```vb
   Dim b as Base 
   Select Case childName
      Case "child1"
        b = New Child1(x)
      Case "child74"
        b = New Child74(x)
      Case "child103"
        b = New Child103(x)
   End Select
   ```
2. Somehow reflect my call to create a generic one (pseudo as I don't know much about this):

   ```vb
   Dim b as Base = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("MyProjectName" & childName))
   ```

   wherein "childName" is one of 170 children and then `b.Process(x)` - this assumes I use a routine called `Process` as I haven't seen any examples of sending values in a constructor in the `CreateInstance` thing.
3. Something else?

Any help/advice/best practice would be welcome (except those that say "*why do you need 170 thing? don't use 170 things*").

Comment: The `Select Case` is clearly going to be significantly faster.  The tradeoff is that you have to modify the code and recompile every time you need to add a new name.  The additional overhead that reflection imposes may not matter.

Comment: Also, despite your warning, you probably really are doing this wrong.  Your solution relies too much on inheritance.  Have you considered using something like an `ExpandoObject`instead?  You get all the same benefits (including dot notation support) without the inheritance aggravation.

Comment: @RobertHarvey.  I agree - 170 classes is not ideal as it's really only internal variables (a ton of them) that are different in each class.I've not worked with `ExpandoObject` before, I'll look it up and see if it will work well for my scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use reflection to build a `Dictionary<string/Type>` instance. Use that to instantiate the correct types based on the string name. You can pass a string comparer to the key/lookup so it is not case sensitive. Build the dictionary only 1x for the life of the application (keep it around in a static field in some Factory class).

This is written in c# but you could port it over to vb.net.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public sealed class Factory
    {
        private static readonly Dictionary<string, Type> TypeLookup;

        static Factory()
        {
            // You could iterate over additional assemblies if needed
            // the key is assumed to be the name of the class (case insensitive)

            TypeLookup = typeof(Factory).Assembly.GetTypes()
                .Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && typeof(SomeBase).IsAssignableFrom(t))
                .ToDictionary(t => t.Name, t => t, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }

        public SomeBase Create(string name)
        {
            Type t;
            if (TypeLookup.TryGetValue(name, out t))
            {
                return (SomeBase) Activator.CreateInstance(t);
            }
            throw new ArgumentException("Could not find type " + name);
        }
    }

    public abstract class SomeBase { }
    public class Child1 : SomeBase { }
    public class Child2 : SomeBase { }
    public class Child3 : SomeBase { }
}
```

Calling code

```
var factory = new Factory();
var child1 = factory.Create("child1");
```

Comment: Wow, this is awesome - thank you! I'm actually going to try this and compare performance against `Select Case`.

Comment: @ToddMain - Glad to help!

Comment: Performance should be almost as good as `select case`, once the dictionary is built.

Comment: AFAIK `Activator.CreateInstance` is really slower than using `new` .

Comment: @Julian : But you can't use `new` in this case. You're pretty much bound to using `Activator.CreateInstance()` unless you want to create long, repetitive `switch` statements.

Comment: @Julian - True but depending on the use case it is probably considered a micro-optimization to spend time speeding this up. If the OP was creating millions of instances in short bursts (or continuously) I would agree this would be too slow. Chances are that is not the case and time spent optimizing would be better spent in other areas of the code (*like anything having to do with I/O*).

Answer (score 2):

We'd all love to have the "fastest, shortest amount to write, best performance" option, but usually it's a tradeoff and you have to choose one!

The "best performance" option would probably be the `Select Case`, but that will take longer to write and will require ongoing maintenance if you add new classes.

The "shortest amount to write" option would probably be to use reflection.  It would take only a few lines of code, and would be self-maintaining.  Something like this would do the trick:

```vb
Dim childNames As String() = New String() {"Child1", "Child2", "Child1", "Child1", "Child3"}
For Each s As String In childNames
    Dim assm As Assembly = GetType(Child1).Assembly
    Dim nmspc As String = "MyNameSpace"
    Dim type As Type = assm.GetType(String.Format("{0}.{1}", nmspc, s))
    Dim obj As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(type)
Next
```

My recommendation would be to try that and see whether it performs up to your expectation - if you are creating a ton of instances, it probably won't, but if you are creating a few at a time, it will probably be fine.  If performance is a problem, then Select Case will be faster.

Of course reflection has lots of haters who will tell you never to use it...  If you're aware of the potential performance issues, you can make an educated decision.

Comment: It's sounding like the `Select Case` may be the way to go as I have 170 classes and won't ever have more or less.

Comment: With 170 classes, I would write a script to write the Select Case...  You can use Assembly.GetTypes() to get an array of your types, check each to see if it inherits from your parent class, and append your boilerplate code to a text file if it does.

Answer (score 1):

Adhering to your footnote, I would do it a combination of 1 and 2.

```vb
Dim b as Base

'Type.GetType may not work in all scenarios
Dim childType As Type = Type.GetType(childName, true, true)

Select Case childType
    'Specific implementations
    Case GetType(ProblemChild)
        b = New ProblemChild(x, y, z)
    Case Else
        b = DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(childType, x), Base)
End Select
```

This will let you get the Type based on the name (do note that you will probably need to feed it the namespace and possibly some other info). Now that you have the type, we can leverage VB.NET's ability to switch off of the class type (C# can now also do this).

Any special implementations can have their stuff explicitly defined in the Select while everything else that is just takes the same standard constructor parameter can be left to the `Activator`.

*Sorry if it doesn't compile right off the bat, VB is a little rusty.*

Comment: Thanks Ty for this. This looks similar to the `Select Case` with just strings, like I would still need to create 170 cases. Is that correct?

Comment: @ToddMain Only for the classes that do not adhere to a standard constructor. Your example showed all taking in `x`. Those all could be handled in the `Case Else`.